# How to calculate the factorial answer to result % the 10,000,001st prime

Tags: java

I need to report my result % the 10,000,001st prime.

Examples of input/output:

1. Enter a natural number (non-negative integer): 12

factorial 120152218

superfactorial: 168016008

ultrafactorial: 170942852

My code to calculate factorial, superfactorial and ultrafactorial:

public class UltraFactorial {

```
public static  int ultrafactorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
      return factorial(n);
    } else {
      return superfactorial(n) * ultrafactorial(n-1);
    }
  }


public static  int superfactorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
          return factorial(n);
        } else {
          return factorial(n) * superfactorial(n-1);
        }
      }


public static  int factorial(int n) {
        if(n == 0 || n == 1) {
          return n;
        } else {
          return n * factorial(n-1);
        }
      }

public static void main(String []args){
Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=console.nextInt();
System.out.println("factorial of n="+factorial(n));

System.out.println("superfactorial of n="+superfactorial(n));
System.out.println("superfactorial of n="+ultrafactorial(n));

}
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am getting supperfactorial, ultrafactorial return 0. Also not sure how to convert answer to % the 10,000,001st prime

Answer (score 0):

This is adorably naive. The ultrafactorial of 5 is:

> 3175 042373 780336 892901 667920 556557 182493 442088 021222 004926 225128 381629 943118 937129 098831 435345 716937 405655 305190 657814 877412 786176 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000

yeah, all of those digits. Imagine how large the ultrafactorial of 12 is. If you start writing it down now, you'll be done a few billion years from now. Better get a pen and paper fast!

An int holds a value between -2147483648 and 2147483647. You're *just a few* digits, short, there.

The ultrafactorial of 12 is astronomically large. It is so large, that if you expended all the ~ 68719476736 bits your computer has as RAM (8GB worth), it wouldn't fit. Not even close. Thus, calculating the ultrafactorial of 12 with a basic computer is impossible / extremely convoluted and requires a sizable harddisk just to store the numbers, let alone do the calculation. It'll probably take many trillions of years to calculate it. The universe might not have enough energy to do it.

But that's why the question includes that little caveat: The answer is within the modspace of the 10,000,001st prime. The idea is, let's say the 10,000,001st prime is X. Then the math works like so: "X-1" is some number. If you add 1 to it, then the result should be 0. No calculation you do in this modspace will ever be X, or larger; instead your numberline is more like a circle: It loops around.

That means no calculation will ever result in a number that is too large to store, assuming you can store the 10,000,001st prime.

Nevertheless, the tricks you need to get up to in computer code to get this job done is not all that simple. You can try this, though: `BigInteger` has a `modPow` method that seems very relevant here:

BigInteger are like ints but they can hold arbitrarily sized values (though, that doesn't change much about the complexity of things: Trying to calculate 12^11^10^9^... with BigInteger still needs a universe-sized god-computer). Crucially, they have the modPow method:

```
    BigInteger TWELVE = BigInteger.valueOf(12);
    BigInteger modFactor = calculate10000001stPrime();
    BigInteger result = TWELVE.modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(11), modFactor);
```

is what you're looking for.

As far superfactorial, I think you just handroll the multiplication as normal, but after every result, modulo the calculation.  Modulo has the property (where `%` is the module operator, as in, `a % b` means: Divide a by b. Ditch the result, but keep the remainder; `11 % 3` is 2. An advantage of modulo is that under most operations, you can freely modulo everything because it 'expands out'.

Let's say that the operation "x * y" has answer "z". Modulo ops have an interesting property: `"(x % c) * (y % c) = (z % c)` as well, for *all* imaginable values of `c`! Note that this 'modulo expands out' thing has limits, but presumably the point of this exercise is that you're supposed to figure out the math behind modulo (or learn it, there are TONS of docs on this, it's used a lot in cryptography). At any rate, I *think*, for superfactorial of, say, 5, go in steps:

> superfac(5) = 5! * 4! * 3! * 2! * 1!

but that's unwieldy and doesn't fit, so instead, make that:

> M = that prime.
> superfacmod(5, M) = (5! % M) ** (4! % M) ** (3! % M) ** (2! % M) ** (1! % M)

Where ** is modulo-multiply, and `5!` is of course `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5`, but you can also do `1 ** 2 ** 3 ** 4 ** 5` instead. You can modulo at all phases without issues. I think if you do that, you can calculate superfacmod(12, M) within a reasonable time.